# unload などのイベントハンドラ内で location.href による画面遷移が出来ない

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

window.openした画面が閉じた場合に画面を遷移させようとしています。
JSファイルの中で以下のように実装するとFireFoxでは画面遷移可能だったのですが、Chromeで試すと画面遷移できませんでした。
ステップ実行でおってみると、下記の部分は実行されるのですが「location.href」の値が変わっていませんでした。

```
location.href = "遷移画面";
```

よくわからないまま下記のような処理に代わると画面が遷移できることを確認できました。

```
setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = "遷移画面";
}, 3000);
```

location.hrefは非同期処理なのでしょうか？
通常location.href = "遷移画面";このような形で画面遷移させるのは問題なのでしょうか？

Comment: 遷移させようとしているのは、window.open でできた window でしょうか、それとも別の windows でしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
呼び元の画面（A）からwindow.openで画面（B）を開き、
Bが閉じられたら、A画面を遷移させようとしています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

下記の Chrome のバグは現在修正されています（https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660496#c29）。
問題が再現されなくなったのを確認しました（Google Chrome 56.0.2924.76）。
2017/01/30

---

#### 本題

Chrome のバグだと思います。
それらしきバグ報告がありました（https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660496）。
下記のようなコードで確認しましたが、`unload` や `beforeunload` のイベントハンドラ内では、確かに `window.location` による移動が出来ませんでした。

```
function open_win(){
    let win = window.open(window.location.href);
    win.addEventListener("unload", (ev)=>{
        window.location.assign("http://ja.stackoverflow.com/");
    });
}
```

#### `location.href` への代入による移動

> 通常 `location.href = "遷移画面";`このような形で画面遷移させるのは問題なのでしょうか？

動くはずですが、[仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface)には見当たらないので、

```
location.assign("http://example.com/");
// あるいは
location = "http://example.com/";
```

の方がよいかも知れません。

#### 非同期か

> `location.href`は非同期処理なのでしょうか？

仕様は理解していませんが、非同期です。
ブラウザが移動の準備を終えた後、JavaScript の実行中でない（イベントを受けつける）タイミングで実際にページを移動します。

```js
function assign_test(){
 window.location.assign("http://ja.stackoverflow.com/");
 window.msg.textContent = "Moving...";
 setInterval(()=>window.msg.textContent+=".", 10);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="assign_test();">Assign</button>
<p id="msg"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox のバグです。
仕様上、unload ハンドラ内でページ遷移を起こすことはできません。

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#navigate
`location.href` への代入でナビゲーション処理が始まりますが、既にアンロードアルゴリズム実行中なのでステップ3で中止となります。

Comment: 私は仕様が理解出来ないのですが、ナビゲーションを起そうとしている `window` と、アンロードされている `window` が別であっても中止するのが仕様上正しいのでしょうか。`setTimeout` で回避出来るのはなぜでしょうか。

Comment: 仕様を読む限りでは、browsing context が別ならページ遷移できそうです。```setTimeout``` で回避できるのは、アンロードアルゴリズムの実行が終わった後になるためです。

Comment: 質問者の場合、「アンロードアルゴリズムの実行が終わった後」約三秒も経った後に `location.href = "遷移画面";` が実行されているわけですから、JavaScript を実行しているのも、遷移させる対象も、アンロードしているページとは「browsing context が別」です。「browsing context が別ならページ遷移できそうです」との事なので、やはり遷移可能な Firefox が正しいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: もとの質問の解釈が違うみたいです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
ちなみにIE11でも試してみたところ、setTimeoutしてもダメでした。

もう画面遷移＝submitでしてみよう！と思い、「location.href = "遷移画面";」箇所を差し替えたところ
IE、Chrome、FireFoxともに画面遷移ができました。（全てWindows）

せっかくですのでMACでもいくつかのブラウザで試してみようと思います。


＞int32_tさま
せっかく教えてくださった
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#navigate
サイトなのですが、どこら辺を読んでいいのかもわからず、「ステップ３」がどこを指しているのかわかりませんでしたTT